# Windows 8 Tab Control Styles in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, silverlight, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to get Windows 8 (Metro UI) style tab controls in my application, similar to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avip/archive/2011/09/19/windows-8-development-tip-tab-control.aspx). However, the code listed only seems to work in Silverlight. I'm using WPF. Is there any easy way to at least get similar styling? I can do without fancy transitions, but I'd like the tabs to look like the Metro UI ones.

Comment: You need to develop in VS11, not VS 2010

Comment: I'm in VC2012, that should work too, correct? The issue is FlipView isn't allowed in WPF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some digging around I found [MahApps](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/), which is extremely easy to install into existing projects (uses NuGet in VS) and the documentation and use is really easy!

Comment: Another very nice Themes engine is Elysium (http://elysium.asvishnyakov.com/en/downloads). It has a nice SDK that works in VS 2012 and VS 2013. I found it to be better and more flexible than MahApps.

Answer (score 2):

You could check [Elysium](http://elysium.codeplex.com/). I've never used it, but it seems to do what you ask for.

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking at it, but there seems to be absolutely no documentation or sample code. The sample app it comes with doesn't come with the code, so I'm not sure if this will work

Comment: There seems to be Elysium.Test project in the [sources](http://elysium.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/16201#319607).

Answer (score 0):

The Metro Style Application have a built in styles, animation and Controls(FlipView , GridVIew and ListView). Even in Silverlight you'll not be able to use this styles. so if you use WPF or Silverlight you must define your own style to make it similar to this.

So make your application in Metro style(Xaml or HTML) or define your own styles for your tab control(SL or WPF)
This post is about the [new Metro Style Control](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-8-Metro-Dealing-with-new-metro-controls.aspx)s that isn't exist in WPF and Silverlight

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. My question is how can I create something similar to Metro Style Tabs?